# References style: last name at first and first name last and Year of references, title of journal & finally Journal name(italics) & Page references

Tags: latex, bibliography, overleaf, biblatex

I'm writing a paper and the journal that I'm trying to submit to requires the following style:

[1] Ghosh R and Naryanan G 2008 Control of three phase, four wire PWPM rectifier. *IIEE Trans. Power Electron*. 24(6): 1444-1452

References should be listed at the end of the paper in serial order to match their order of appearance in the text. References (number type) should be cited in the text and in the list with serial order as base line numbers with square brackets.

which bibliography style is this?